# Using visual mode without changing gv

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

I'm working on a plugin and I use visual selections all the time in my code. Stuff like `normal! v{:call whatever()\<cr>`.

The problem is that if the user does `gv` in his file it won't select his last visual selection, but the last visual selection used by my plugin.

So is there any way I can prevent that from happening?

Comment: `gv` uses the marks `<` and `>`. Presumably you could save them away and restore them in your code, but I'm not sure how you would do that without actually visiting the location `'<` and saving that location to a different mark....

Comment: This isn't really a full answer, but there is a plugin for saving visual selections like marks or registers. It's called [Visual Marks](https://github.com/iago-lito/vim-visualMarks). Peering through the source code, or including it in your plugin might help you figure it out.

Comment: Yes, you can save and restore the `>` and `<` marks using `getpos()`/`setpos()`. I do that for the NrrwRgn plugin. This needs patch 7.3.590

Comment: `v{:command` could be expressed with `.,'}command`. Maybe you could use visual mode a little less.

Comment: This still clobbers another mark but you could also use the command `:'<mark p` to copy mark `<` to mark `p`.

Comment: Awsome, I managed to do it with with the marks and `getups()`/`stepos()`. Thank you guys!

Comment: On a side note: you might want to look at the [textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) plugin and the [text objects](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/wiki) already defined with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments by @Tumbler41 and @ChristianBrabant I managed to do it like this:

```
let l:lastSelectionStart = getpos("'<")
let l:lastSelectionEnd = getpos("'>")

" My code...

call setpos("'<", l:lastSelectionStart)
call setpos("'>", l:lastSelectionEnd)
```