# Make operator that doesn't change gv

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode, custom-text-object, operator-pending-mode

I'm trying to redefine my inner and outer line text objects so that they don't change `gv`. First I had

```
onoremap <silent> il :<C-u>normal! $v^<CR>
```

I changed it based on [Using visual mode without changing gv](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9054/using-visual-mode-without-changing-gv)

```
onoremap <silent> il :<C-u>let lastSelectionStart = getpos("'<") \| let lastSelectionEnd = getpos("'>") \| execute "normal! $v^" \| call setpos("'<", lastSelectionStart) \| call setpos("'>", lastSelectionEnd)<CR>
```

But it doesn't seem to have had the intended effect

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible *within* the operator-pending mode mapping.

The **whole** right-hand side of an operator-pending mode mapping is meant to visually select the area on which you want to operate. Said another way, the visual area on which the operator is going to operate is only defined *after* the **whole** RHS of the mapping has been executed.

This means that restoring `'<` and `'>` at any point in the RHS happens *before* the desired visual area is actually defined, and thus that the final `'<` and `'>` override whatever you set within the RHS.

It *should* be feasible by storing `'<` and `'>` *before* getting into operator-pending mode and restoring them *after* the operator+motion combo, but that would mean overriding each and every possible combo with a wrapper… which doesn't sound like a good idea at all.

Maybe there is a better approach?

Comment: I guess `gv` could be remapped to restore and use the old `'<`, if visual mode has not been used in-between... which would require remapping visual mode entry keybinds too?